# Error while using max() function in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame `inp_df` which contains column `'DEINR'` with buildings numbers. Type of this column is *object* since there are values like "44a" or "14c/1". When I try to do `inp_df['DEINR'].min()` or `.max()` I'm getting an error:

```
'<=' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'
```

What should I do to be able to do min/max with this column? Thanks!

Comment: Remove the letters ? How do you compare 44a and 14c/1 ?

Comment: your column contains `str` and `float` so it cannot perform `max`. You can try to just take rows with floats and do `max` on that or convert the `str` in some ways to `float`.

Comment: @azro 14c/1 should come first. Min/max works fine with strings, thats why I'm asking this question.

Comment: @hadik how it can contain several datatypes if `inp_df['DEINR'].dtype` is `dtype('O')` ?

Answer (score 1):

The data type of `DEINR` column is object, since it has both `float` and `str` values. First, you need to convert the whole column to `str` type and then you can compute `min()` or `max()` on that column.

```py
d = {'col1': ['14c', 2], 'col2': ['432a', 4]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)

df.dtypes
```

Output:

```
col1    object
col2    object
dtype: object
```

Converting the column to `str` dtype:

```py
df['col1'] = df['col1'].astype(str)

df['col1'].min()
```

Output:

```py
'14c'
```

Hope this is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Both string and float values are present in the column 'DEINR'. Or You can covert to float.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this by catching TypeError.

```
minimum_values = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Minimum Value'])
for v in list(inp_df.columns.values):
    try:
        minimum_values.loc[v] = [inp_df[v].min()]
    except TypeError:
        minimum_values.loc[v] ='N/A'
```

Thanks!