# TypeError for >= between float and string values

Tags: python, excel, pandas, dataframe

I have been using the below script to calculate the storage capacity on one of our server environments. It reads the values from a report I get every two weeks and then creates a file I can import into PowerBI to create graphs. It ran without an issue 2 weeks ago but today when I tried to run it I get a TypeError. I assume it is "if float(df['Capacity(TB)']) >= 0.01: " causing the issue as per the error message.

The data I am importing is a xls sheet with a header name and values underneath it. I had a look to see if there are any blank fields but could not find any. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

```
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import os
from os import listdir
from os.path import isfile, join

#SCCM resource import as 'df'
pathres = r'C:\Capacity Reports\SCOM Reports'

onlyfiles = [f for f in listdir(pathres) if isfile(join(pathres, f))]

df = pd.DataFrame()

for i in onlyfiles:
    print(i)
    dfresimp = pd.read_excel(pathres+'\\'+i)
    df = pd.concat([df, dfresimp])

#CMDB import as 'df2'
df2 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Capacity Reports\\CMDB_Export.xlsx') 

#Windows Lifecycle import as 'df3'
df3 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Capacity Reports\\Windows Server Lifecycle.xlsx') 

#SCVMM clusters import as 'df4'
df4 = pd.read_excel('C:\\Capacity Reports\\HyperV Overview.xlsx') 

#SCVMM Storage reports import as 'df5'
pathstor = r'C:\Capacity Reports\Hyper-V Storage'

Storfiles = [f for f in listdir(pathstor) if isfile(join(pathstor, f))]

df5 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in Storfiles:
    print(i)
    dfstorimp = pd.read_excel(pathstor+'\\'+i)
    df5 = pd.concat([df5, dfstorimp])   

#CREATE MAIN TABLE 

df['NAME'] = df['Computer Name'].str.upper() 

df11 = pd.DataFrame() 

df11['NAME'] = df2['NAME'].str.upper()
df11['Application Owner'] = df2['Application Owner'].str.title()
df11['HW EOSL'] = df2['HW EOSL'].str.title()

#print(df11['HW EOSL'])

Main_Table = df.merge(df11, on='NAME', how='left')
Main_Table = Main_Table.merge(df3, on='Operating System Edition', how='left')

df13 = pd.DataFrame()
df13['Hyper V Cluster name'] = df4['Hyper V Cluster name']
df13['Computer Name'] = df4['Server Name'].str.upper()

Main_Table = Main_Table.merge(df13, on='Computer Name', how='left')

Main_Table['OS_Support'] = pd.to_datetime(Main_Table['Extended_Support_End_Date'], format='"%Y-%m-%d %H:%S:%f')

Main_Table['OS_Support'] = Main_Table['OS_Support'].dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

#print(Main_Table['OS_Support'])



def f(df): 

    if df['Host/GuestVM'] == 'GuestVM': 

        result = (df['Total Physical Memory GB']-(df['Total Physical Memory GB']*(df['Memory % Used Max Value']/100)))/2 
        return result 
    else: 
        np.nan 
        
Main_Table['Reclaimable Memory Calculated'] = Main_Table.apply(f, axis=1)         


def f(df): 

    if df['Host/GuestVM'] == 'GuestVM': 

        result = (df['Total Logical Processors']-(df['Total Logical Processors']*(df['CPU % Used Max Value']/100)))/2
        return result 
    else: 
        np.nan   

Main_Table['Reclaimable CPU Calculated'] = Main_Table.apply(f, axis=1) 
           
Main_Table['Reclaimable Memory Calculated'] = round(Main_Table['Reclaimable Memory Calculated'])
Main_Table['Reclaimable CPU Calculated'] = round(Main_Table['Reclaimable CPU Calculated'])

Main_Table['Report Timestamp'] = Main_Table['Report Timestamp'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")

Main_Table = Main_Table.drop_duplicates()

Main_Table['Report Timestamp Number'] = Main_Table['Report Timestamp']

column = Main_Table["Report Timestamp Number"]

max_value = column.max()
Total_Memory_Latest = 0

def f(df):
    
    global Total_Memory_Latest

    if df['Report Timestamp Number'] == max_value and df['Host/GuestVM'] == 'Host':

        Total_Memory_Latest += df['Total Physical Memory GB']
        
        return 0
    else:
        np.nan

Main_Table['DummyField'] = Main_Table.apply(f, axis=1)        

Main_Table.to_excel(r'C:\Users\storm_he\OneDrive - MTN Group\Documents\Testing\Main_Table.xlsx')



#CREATE STORAGE TABLE AND EXPORT

def f(df):
    
     
        #if df['Host/GuestVM'] == 'Host': 
        
        #try:
            if float(df['Capacity(TB)']) >= 0.01: 
                result = (df['Available(TB)']/df['Capacity(TB)'])*100
                return round(result)
            else:
                return ''
        #except:
            #return np.nan
        
df5['% Storage free'] = df5.apply(f, axis=1)

pattern = '|'.join(['.mtn.co.za', '.mtn.com'])
df5['VMHost'] = df5['VMHost'].str.replace(pattern,'')
df5['VMHost'] = df5['VMHost'].str.upper()

df5['Report Timestamp'] = df5['Report Timestamp'].dt.strftime("%Y%m%d")
#print(df5['Report Timestamp'])

df5.to_excel(r'C:\Users\storm_he\OneDrive - MTN Group\Documents\Testing\Main_Storage_table.xlsx')

    
print('Run Finished')
```

StackTrace

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-3c53bb32e311> in <module>
    108 column = Main_Table["Report Timestamp Number"]
    109 
--> 110 max_value = column.max()
    111 Total_Memory_Latest = 0
    112 

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in stat_func(self, axis, skipna, level, numeric_only, **kwargs)
  11212         if level is not None:
  11213             return self._agg_by_level(name, axis=axis, level=level, skipna=skipna)
> 11214         return self._reduce(
  11215             f, name, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, numeric_only=numeric_only
  11216         )

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in _reduce(self, op, name, axis, skipna, numeric_only, filter_type, **kwds)
   3889                 )
   3890             with np.errstate(all="ignore"):
-> 3891                 return op(delegate, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
   3892 
   3893         # TODO(EA) dispatch to Index

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in f(values, axis, skipna, **kwds)
    123                     result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    124             else:
--> 125                 result = alt(values, axis=axis, skipna=skipna, **kwds)
    126 
    127             return result

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\nanops.py in reduction(values, axis, skipna, mask)
    835                 result = np.nan
    836         else:
--> 837             result = getattr(values, meth)(axis)
    838 
    839         result = _wrap_results(result, dtype, fill_value)

~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _amax(a, axis, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     28 def _amax(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,
     29           initial=_NoValue, where=True):
---> 30     return umr_maximum(a, axis, None, out, keepdims, initial, where)
     31 
     32 def _amin(a, axis=None, out=None, keepdims=False,

TypeError: '>=' not supported between instances of 'float' and 'str'
```

Comment: Could you post the stacktrace? Usually the error prints the line where it occurs. Just from your big chunk of code it'd take a lot of effort to guess where the error comes from.

Comment: Does this help you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61385248/error-while-using-max-function-in-pandas I searched for `TypeError column.max()` and this came up

Comment: The data looks like this. Its a header and then only numbers. "Capacity(TB)"
5,50
5,00
5,00

Comment: If I convert it to str I will no longer be able to use the >= function as I need to exclude drives smaller than 100Mb

Comment: Ok, I'm not much into pandas, but couldn't you just remove the header column (if it isn't done automatically) and then convert everything to float (instead of str)?